# Solving a system of congruence equations

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let's consider the system:

$\alpha x_1+\beta \equiv 0 \space (mod26)$

$\alpha x_2+\beta \equiv 1 \space (mod26)$

I want to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ given $x_1, \space x_2$.

Subtracting the two equations i get:
$\alpha (x_2-x_1) \equiv 1 \space (mod26)$
So i have to find the multiplicative inverse of $(x_2-x_1)$, and it's only possible if $gcd((x_2-x_1),26)=1$

At this point,
$\alpha = (x_2-x_1)^{-1}$
and 
$\beta = \frac{-x_1}{x_2-x_1}$

It it correct ?

Comment: What makes you think that $x_2-x_1$ will have a multiplicative inverse?

Comment: Since it's a known ciphertext attack, i think i have to choose $x_2, \space x_1$ so as $x_2-x_1$ and 26 are coprime. Is this true ?

Comment: Any help ??? :(((